# Diferencias entre FETCH ABSOLUTE y FETCH RELATIVE

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, cursor, fetch

Estoy trabajando con cursores cuyo parametro de comportamiento es `SCROLL`pero no comprendo cual es el objetivo de dos de sus funciones a la hora de hacer el `FETCH`.

No entiendo ni que hacen ni para que sirven FETCH ABSOLUTE y FETCH RELATIVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como sabes el operador `FETCH` sirve para extraer filas del cursor resultante según la consulta que hayas invocado, al utlizar como tu dices la opción `SCROLL` eso sirve para declarar que el cursor de la información resultante sera multidireccional.

¿Qué quiere decir esto?
Si tu, al momento de crear un cursor no lo declaras con la opción `SCROLL` se considera un cursor de tipo unidireccional lo cual nos indica que el resultado o la tabla de resultados que tu recibes de determinado cursor solo lo podrás recorrer en una sola dirección y por ende cada resultado de dicho cursor solo lo podrás leer una sola ocasión como mucho.

Por otro lado al declarar la opción `SCROLL` el cursor resultante o tu tabla de resultados lo vas a poder leer hacia cualquier sentido gracias a los operadores

> FETCH
>             [ [ NEXT | PRIOR | FIRST | LAST
>                       | ABSOLUTE { n | @nvar }
>                       | RELATIVE { n | @nvar }
>                  ]

NEXT: Lee la fila siguiente, si recién comenzaste a leer el cursor el resultado será el primer registro de tu cursor (unica opción para cursores `NO SCROLL`).

PRIOR: Lee la fila anterior.

FIRST: Lee la primera fila del cursor.

LAST: Lee la última fila del cursor.

ABSOLUTE n: Lee la fila del cursor que indica la posición "n"
Por ejemplo, si el cursor tiene 7 resultados:

```
  Col1        Col2
 Resultado     1
 Resultado     2
 Resultado     3
 Resultado     4
 Resultado     5
 Resultado     6
 Resultado     7
```

y tu defines lo siguiente:

```
 FETCH ABSOLUTE 2 FROM cursor;
```

Obtendrás el registro (Resultado 2)

RELATIVE n: Lee el registro que indique el valor de "n" en base a la fila en que te encuentres
Por ejemplo, dada la situación anterior, te encuentras en la fila número 2 del cursor y tu defines lo siguiente:

```
 FETCH RELATIVE 3 FROM cursor;
```

Obtendrás el registro (Resultado 5)

Espero la respuesta sea de ayuda, de igual forma échale una leída a este libro, esta bueno y explica de manera clara el funcionamiento de los cursores.

https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=vsYTINIEwd4C&pg=PT210&lpg=PT210&dq=para+que+sirve+fetch+absolute+sql+server&source=bl&ots=k1WdPvrqPP&sig=jkMSKjjm7MzTaMchZCnDWAEJULM&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxlP6GrNPbAhVROKwKHUYID20Q6AEIpwEwDg#v=onepage&q=para%20que%20sirve%20fetch%20absolute%20sql%20server&f=false

Comment: De gran ayuda tu respuesta! Clara y concisa! Gracias!